# Unable to pass wandb API Key in PyCharm terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, wandb

```
wandb: (1) Create a W&B account
wandb: (2) Use an existing W&B account
wandb: (3) Don't visualize my results
wandb: Enter your choice: 2
wandb: You chose 'Use an existing W&B account'
wandb: Logging into wandb.ai. (Learn how to deploy a W&B server locally: https://wandb.me/wandb-server)
wandb: You can find your API key in your browser here: https://wandb.ai/authorize
wandb: Paste an API key from your profile and hit enter, or press ctrl+c to quit:
```

Here my terminal in PyCharm freezes an I have no means whatsoever to enter or paste my API Key. On pressing enter nothing happens either.
**Any help or ideas?**

Comment: You are not able to paste and press the enter key?

Comment: Yes exactly and as written I am also not able to paste something and then press enter.

Comment: From [doc](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/cli/wandb-login), you can use `wandb login [OPTIONS] [KEY]...` provide key here like this.

Comment: Yes that is what I found from an issue report on their github. Will edit your more generalized answer into the existing one. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found an issue report on their GitHub
> [here](https://github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/2878).

There is also a **workaround** proposed. Before even prompted to enter your API key you can do so in advance from your terminal like so..

```
wandb login xxxxxxxxxYOUR_KEY_HERExxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Or more generalized from @shaik moeed's comment refering to their [documentation](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/cli/wandb-login):

```
wandb login [OPTIONS] [KEY]
```

You will then not be asked to enter your Key later on and you won't get stuck.

*Note:* This is a workaround, not sure why my terminal did not like me to paste stuff, would still be nice to know whether you guys can reproduce or whether it's me.